# google play developer console crash/anr logs

Tags: android, google-play-console

i can no longer see the crash stacks for both anrs and crashes only a brief overview of the what caused the crash. for example:

```
Contect.startForegroundService() did not then callService.startForeground()
```

Previously I was able to see the exact line of code, now I cannot. I have tried finding any option to enable this to no avail.
All proguard files have been uploaded, how would i re-enable this?

Answer (score 0):

the issue was the page wasnt scaling properly, since google moved the stack traces to a seperate button that needed to be clicked it was out of view.
this affects firefox.